# How to add custom domains(SSL enabled) to user profile in Django?

Tags: django, ssl, dns, django-rest-framework, ssl-certificate

I have a Django (DRF) enabled web app where users can create their profile. Profile url looks like this - https://mywebsite.com/username . I want to add a feature where users can map their custom domain(buy a new domain or use existing domain)to the profile page. How do I do this? How to make sure SSL is enabled in all custom domains without making my users buy separate SSL certificates?

Answer (score 0):

If the user can custom the sub domain only (*.mywebsite.com) you can buy a wildcard SSL certificate

If you want your users to choose any domain, it's not possible to do that without creating an SSL for each domain, you can use Let's Encrypt, but you will need domain verification and other things that aren't handle by Django (like reverse proxy with Nginx)

Comment: I think I can make use of SAN certificates as all my custom domains will point to the same IP address. https://www.digicert.com/subject-alternative-name.htm 
But how do I make use of Django sites framework(or any other method) to let my users use custom domains of their choice ?